# RecyclerView onClick to different activity on each position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I am a newbie and want to ask question about onClick RecyclerView.

I found this script from `http://wimsonevel.blogspot.co.id/2016/03/tutorial-android-recyclerview-and.html`

I have successfully created an intent to another activity by this code:

```
    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Member member = memberList.get(position);

    holder.memberThumb.setImageResource(member.getThumb());
    holder.memberName.setText(member.getName());
    holder.memberTeam.setText(member.getTeam());
    holder.memberCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent go;

                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);

        }

    });

}
```

But I want to add intent to each CardView position. If position 0, go to Main0Activity, If position 1, go to Main1Activity, etc.

My code (not work):

```
    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Member member = memberList.get(position);

    holder.memberThumb.setImageResource(member.getThumb());
    holder.memberName.setText(member.getName());
    holder.memberTeam.setText(member.getTeam());
    holder.memberCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent go;

            if (position==0){
                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main0Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);
            }
            else if (position==1){
                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main1Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);
            }
            else if (position==2){
                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);
            }
            else if (position==3){
                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main3Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);
            }
            else if (position==4){
                go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main4Activity.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(go);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Error:

```
Error:(74, 73) error: <anonymous com.example.wim.androidrecyclerview.adapter.MemberListAdapter$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener

Error:(76, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

How to fix this?

Thanks

Sorry for my bad English

Full code: `https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e15b222bfc20ba21eaf5c2c8d566166b`

Comment: yes it's already on manifest

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: I update the question with the error

Comment: Do not Override onItemClick Method. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onClick` method.
Try this one,

```
 @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Member member = memberList.get(position);

        holder.memberThumb.setImageResource(member.getThumb());
        holder.memberName.setText(member.getName());
        holder.memberTeam.setText(member.getTeam());
        holder.memberCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent go;

                if (position==0){
                    go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main0Activity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(go);
                }
                else if (position==1){
                    go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main1Activity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(go);
                }
                else if (position==2){
                    go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(go);
                }
                else if (position==3){
                    go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main3Activity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(go);
                }
                else if (position==4){
                    go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main4Activity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(go);
                }
        }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add click listener on itemview like this `holder.itemview.setOnClickListener`

```
@Override

public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Member member = memberList.get(position);

holder.memberThumb.setImageResource(member.getThumb());
holder.memberName.setText(member.getName());
holder.memberTeam.setText(member.getTeam());
holder.itemview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent go;

        if (position==0){
            go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main0Activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(go);
        }
        else if (position==1){
            go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main1Activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(go);
        }
        else if (position==2){
            go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(go);
        }
        else if (position==3){
            go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main3Activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(go);
        }
        else if (position==4){
            go = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main4Activity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(go);
        }
    }

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onClick`  like in your first example. If you need position `onBindViewHolder` provides it to you:

> public void onBindViewHolder(MemberViewHolder holder, int **position**) {
>
> }